# Is there any way to grep the **svn** commit message and use that message to block or allow build in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, svn

Is there any way to grep the svn commit message and use that message to block or allow build in jenkins. Like if any developer commit a message that is not as per the standard (which will be defined)then build will not processed in jenkins.I've spend days to find the perfect solution. Please help

Comment: Did you try using pre commit hook to block the commit if it doesnt meet your commit message standard?

Comment: I wrote a script that will block the commit if no message is passed at the time of commit.
/usr/bin/svnlook log -t $2 $1 | grep .... > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        exit 0
else
        exit 1
fi
please let me know how can i match the committed message.

Comment: You should mention what you are trying to match or how does a commit message template for you looks like. Like for example "Work Item:xxxxx Some message " This could  be one of your commit message template.